# Adding a value into a field

Tags: mysql

Inherited a 20,000 book database with a particular field called 'keywords' that is a mess, in one huge table called books.
Trying to prepend a value to each of the 'keywords' fields that reads the words in that field and identifies its exact category with one clear phrase.

So, looking for the word 'ancient' and prepending the value 'menu-ancient'.

```
UPDATE books SET keywords=CONCAT('menu-ancient, ',keywords) 
where keywords like '%ancient%';
```

That works, but then the following query doesn't do what I want!

It's supposed to find all the ones its just done and go through them to find which of them also have the word 'medieval' in there - to give the submenu menu-ancient-medieval as well.

```
UPDATE books SET keywords=CONCAT('menu-ancient-medieval, ',keywords) 
where keywords = 'menu-ancient' AND keywords LIKE '%medieval%';
```

One example field is this:
menu-ancient, WAR., MIDDLE AGES, ANCIENT AND MEDIEVAL, ANCIENT TO 19TH CENTURY,

I have got the menu-ancient prepended but getting nowhere with the medieval bit!

Comment: If I'm understanding your explanation, should this not just be changed from `keywords = 'menu-ancient'` to `keywords LIKE 'menu-ancient%'` ?

Comment: The first UPDATE works fine, and correctly inserts the new value 'menu-ancient. But when the next line of the query, the next UPDATE, is executed it fails to find the word 'medieval'. I did try the LIKE method and ended up with "menu-ancient-medieval, menu-ancient-ancient-ancient, menu-ancient, menu-ancient, NOISBN, PUNIC WARS. ROME, ANCIENT AND MEDIEVAL, ANCIENT TO 19TH CENTURY,  I am wondering if trying to execute 30 queries one after the other constructing sub menus is too many!

Comment: The equality comparison (**`=`** operator) isn't going to match any rows that were just updated by prepending **`'menu-ancient, '`** to the existing value. The equality comparison is only going to match values of `keywords` column that match the specified string. The comma added to the column value is going to cause the equality comparison to `'menu-ancient'` to return FALSE. Consider making use of a `LIKE` comparison or the `FIND_IN_SET` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find_in_set() function to do this.

This works like in the following example :

```
SELECT * from books where FIND_IN_SET('menu-ancient', keywords) > 0;
```

You can apply this to your update query

```
UPDATE books 
SET keywords=CONCAT('menu-ancient-medieval, ',keywords)
where
  FIND_IN_SET('menu-ancient', keywords)
  AND keywords LIKE '%medieval%';
```

NOTE: I'm not quite sure I understand your second part of the question correctly. I guess you may have to alter the query to use a subquery in your where clause.

Comment: 2nd part meant - if keyword 'ancient' exists, the prepend menu-ancient. Next query says, if keyword (now) exists, and keyword 'medieval' is also there, then prepend 'menu-ancient-medieval'

Comment: I thought EACH query would operate on the database. However I now think that ALL the queries operate on the database. It is not updated after each query, for the next query to work on, but all queries do their bit, then the database is updated. How can I get, what will be 80 queries done without entering one after the other in phpmyadmin.